# Query dbpedia to find possible contexts to disambiguate a word

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia, disambiguation

Good day, stackoverflow,

I need to suggest to user different contexts for a word, so that he could have a possibility to disambuguate it.

For example: a word "**less**" can be Unix program, css framework or some other things. A word "**apple**" can be a fruit, a corporation, a river, a state in the US (big apple) or a bunch of other things.

I hope you got the idea.

I looked over the internet and so far I could come up only with [this](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?concept%20?conceptLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?s%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28?label%29%20=%20%27en%27%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?label%20bif%3acontains%20%22apple%22%20.%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?s%20dbpedia-owl%3awikiPageDisambiguates%20?concept%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?concept%20rdfs%3alabel%20?conceptLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28STR%28?conceptLabel%29,%20%22apple%22,%20%22i%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28?conceptLabel%29%20=%20%27en%27%29%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A) query.

But it's still far from being perfect. It often gives too much or too few words and sometimes nothing (for "jquery").

http://www.visualdataweb.org/relfinder/relfinder.php seems to use dbpedia as well, but its results are far better than mine.

How should I change my query to get more relevant results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking for a Web API, use: [DBpedia Lookup](http://spotlight.dbpedia.org) or [DBpedia Spotlight](http://spotlight.dbpedia.org). If you need to do it in SPARQL, you can use the [DBpedia Lexicalization Dataset](http://dbpedia.org/Datasets/NLP).

For DBpedia Lookup, you can give a string and retrieve DBpedia Resources with labels matching those strings:
[lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=apple](http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=apple)

For DBpedia Spotlight, you can optionally give more context:
[spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/candidates?text=apple+company+macintosh+computer](http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/candidates?text=apple%20company%20macintosh%20computer)

For the Lexicalization Dataset, there is no SPARQL endpoint available yet. You will need to [download it](http://lookup.dbpedia.org/api/search.asmx/KeywordSearch?QueryString=apple), load it in your own RDF store and run a query like this:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT ?resource ?score WHERE {
GRAPH ?g {
  ?resource skos:altLabel ?label.
}
  ?g <http://dbpedia.org/spotlight/score> ?score.
  FILTER (REGEX(?label, "apple", "i"))
}
```

Comment: I asked the same question on http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/16309/query-dbpedia-to-find-possible-contexts-to-disambiguate-a-word . Your http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/candidates?text=adobe seems to give better results for "adobe" (not in json, though), but no results for "less. Anyway, thanks for the help, I'll the "lexicalization" solution soon enough

Comment: In order to get the desired output format, you need to do content negotiation. Add an accept header to your request. Example: `curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/candidates?text=adobe`

Comment: The phrase "less" does not return results because the current implementation is filtering out surface forms containing only stopwords. This limitation will be removed in the near future.

Comment: @PabloMendes I was trying to download the dbpedia Lexicalization dataset. But it's not working.